# Hibernate - Cascade delete not working for 2nd level child

Tags: java, hibernate

I've three tables with one to many relationship between table 1 -- table 2 and between table2 -- and table3.

Table1 has composite primary key with two columns - Col_A & Col_B

> ### Table1
>
> Col_A
>   Col_B
>   ....other columns

Tabl2 has composite primary key with three columns Col_A, Col_B and Col_C. 
Col_A & Col_B values come from Table1 but there is no Foreign key relationship defined in the database schema (this is an old legacy database.. and I can't add constraints now because of the data issues)

> ### Table2
>
> Col_A
>   Col_B
>   Col_C
>   ---other columns

Table3 has composite primary key with four columns. Again, there is no foreign key relationship between table 2 and table3.

> ### Table3
>
> Col_A
>
> Col_B
>
> Col_C
>
> Col_D
>
> ---- other columns

And I've defined my domain object mapping in following way..

```
ClassOne{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableOneId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classOne")  
    private Set<ClassTwo> classTwoList = new HashSet<ClassTwo>(0); 

}

 TableOneId{
     //I've omitted the column name annotations for simplicity
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
}

ClassTwo{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableTwoId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "classTwo")  
    private Set<ClassThree> classTwoList = new HashSet<ClassThree>(0); 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false) 
    })
    private ClassOne classOne;
}

 TableTwoId{
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
      private String colC;
}


ClassThree{

    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private TableThreeId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_A",insertable=false, updatable=false),
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_B",insertable=false, updatable=false) ,
       @JoinColumn(name="COL_C",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private ClassTwo classTwo;
}

 TableThreeId{
      private String colA;
      private String colB;
      private String colC;
      private String colD;
}
```

With the above mapping configuration, inserts into the three tables are working as expected. When I call session.save(classOne), I can see that the records are getting inserted into all three tables.

But when I call session.delete(classOne), only the entries from Table1 and Table2 are getting deleted but not the entries from Table3. And since there is no Foreign Key constraint, there is no error thrown by DB either. Since I can't add foreign key constraint at this time, what changes do I need to make to the mapping so that Table3 entries are deleted?

Comment: The cacade are set so this should work... are you sure you are fetching classTwoList  correctly? meaning when you delete all the list are populated as expected?

Comment: @Zeromus.. yep.. this issue turned out to be something else. Before I call, `session.delete(classOne)`, I'm loading the `classOne` from the database by calling `session.get()`.. but because of a mapping issue, classTwo had empty collection of classThree. That's why, when I called delete,  classThree didn't get delete.